# Number of solutions of cyclic-5 system of equations

Tags: proof-verification, maple

I have a series of questions which ask me to, in various ways, to find the number of solutions of the following cyclic-5 problem:

\begin{align}a+b+c+d+e&=0\\
ab+bc+cd+de+ea &=0\\
abc+bcd+cde+dea+eab&=0\\
abcd+bcde+cdea+deab+eabc&=0\\
abcde-1&=0\end{align}

My problem arises when checking my answers - I am currently getting different results for different methods and I would like to know which, if any, are correct.

I have tried using Maple's $\mathtt{solve}$ command which gives me $20$ solutions, except these are of the following form:

\begin{align}a&=1\\
b&=1\\
c&=\mathtt{RootOf}\left(Z^2+3Z+1\right)\\
d&=-\mathtt{RootOf}\left(Z^2+3Z+1\right)-3\\
e&=1\end{align}

Given that $$\mathtt{RootOf}\left(Z^2+3Z+1\right) = \begin{cases}\frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}2\\\\\frac{\sqrt{5}-3}2\end{cases}$$

this 'solution' given by Maple actually contains $4$ solutions.

Now, I could go through these Maple 'solutions' and count up how many solutions each 'solution' gives and then work out how many there are in total, but this is prone to error and would take a long time.

Is there a way of getting Maple to list all the solutions individually? Or somewhere else I could turn to for a definite answer (WolframAlpha times out on me for this computation or I would go there!)?

Comment: i have computed the Solutions with Mathematica, the result is big, sen me you email adress and i can send you the notebook

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I don't need to know what the solutions are, merely how many of them there are. I would rather not share a personal email address, are you able to tell me how many solutions I should expect please

Comment: Multiplying a solution by a fifth root of unity yields another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Maple 2017.2,

```
restart;

sys:={a+b+c+d+e=0,
      a*b+b*c+c*d+d*e+e*a=0,
      a*b*c+b*c*d+c*d*e+d*e*a+e*a*b=0,
      a*b*c*d+b*c*d*e+c*d*e*a+d*e*a*b+e*a*b*c=0,
      a*b*c*d*e-1=0}:

# These contain the implicit RootOfs.
sols_impl:=[solve(sys)]:

nops(sols_impl);

                                 20

sols:=[solve(sys, {a,b,c,d,e}, explicit, allsolutions)]:

nops(sols());

                                 70

# Another way to get all the explicit solutions
# from those containing the implicit RootOfs.

temp:=allvalues(sols_impl):
sols_alt:={seq(op(temp[i]), i=1..nops([temp]))}:

nops(sols_alt);

                                 70

# They are the same.

{op(sols)} minus sols_alt;

                                 {}

sols_alt minus {op(sols)};

                                 {}

evalb( {op(sols)} = sols_alt );

                                true
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much!